# CanonicalName not used for generated class in Cloud Endpoint V2

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

During the Migration of our Cloud Endpoint from v1 to V2, we noticed that the name of the Service Definition class generated in the client does not use canonicalName defined in the @Api annotation definition

For example

```
@Api(name = "customer",
canonicalName = "CustomerAPI",
version = "v1",
...
public class CustomerEndpoint {
...
```

Generates customer-v1-java.zip and the Service Definition class is generated with the name Customer rather than CustomerAPI.

Our app's build.gradle looks as follows

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-client'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

...

dependencies {

    ...

    endpointsServer project(path: ':servers:api', configuration: 'endpoints')
}
```

While the build.gradle in servers/api is as follows

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    // App Engine Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'

    // Endpoints Frameworks Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

...

apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

...

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
    compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
    compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk', version: '1.9.49'
    compile group: 'com.google.endpoints', name: 'endpoints-framework', version: '2.0.8'

...

}

appengine {
    deploy {   // deploy configuration
        version = findProperty("appengine.deploy.version")
        def promoteProp = findProperty("appengine.deploy.promote")
        if (promoteProp != null) {
            promote = new Boolean(promoteProp)
        }
    }
    run {
        host = "0.0.0.0"
        port = 8080
        jvmFlags = ['-Ddatastore.backing_store=../../../local_db.bin']
    }
}

def projectId = 'some-api-project'

endpointsServer {
    hostname = "${projectId}.appspot.com"
}

endpointsClientLibs {
    hostname = "${projectId}.appspot.com"
}
```

Any ideas why the canonicalName is not being respected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, it's a bug/accidentally omission. I will have it fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND

As saiyr pointed out, this is a bug that will be fixed in the next release.

For anyone looking for a workaround, this is what I did in the meantime to get around the problem. Turns out the problem is with the generation of the discovery doc. If you have the correct discovery doc, everything else works just fine.

Generate the client library using the standard gradle dependency in build.gradle of the app

```
endpointsServer project(path: ':servers:api', configuration: 'endpoints')
```

This will generate the discovery docs under the folder

```
app/build/endpointsDiscoveryDocsFromDependencies
```

Copy the discovery docs in this folder into a new folder say

```
app/docs/api/discovery
```

Now edit the build.gradle of the app and comment out the endpoint dependency and add a target to generate the client libraries from a given set of discovery docs

```
dependencies {

    ...

    // Commented out to suppress generation of client library
    // endpointsServer project(path: ':servers:api', configuration: 'endpoints')

}

// Use this target to generate client library instead
endpointsClient {
    discoveryDocs = [
            'docs/api/discovery/customer-v1-rest.discovery',
    ]
}
```

Hope that helps.